# Update assetlinks.json for handling Dynamic Links without prompting for browser in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to handle dynamic links in my android app. But on clicking the link, it prompts to either open it with browser or with my app. I followed this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive) and have checked the section "Handling Dynamic Links using App Links" but I am not getting how to update the assetlinks.json file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do it by setting up your android app in the firebase console and adding your SHA256. Is that set up properly for yours?

Comment: It was not set. After adding, it started working fine. Thanks!

Comment: @IanBarber ,I set it to debug SHA256 ,but now I do not know how to change it to release SHA256 though I have added the release SHA256 to firebase console but it stills reference the debug one.Tell me what to do?